# How to run a capistrano task within a whenever task?

Tags: capistrano, capistrano3, whenever, whenever-capistrano

I have `whenever` gem setup properly. How can I run that `capistrano` from my `whenever` `schedule.rb`?

my schedule.rb

```
every 1.minute, roles: [:app] do
   # how to run here a capistrano task
   # invoke 'my_app:test'
end
```

My capistrano task:

```
namespace :my_app do

  desc 'test'

  task :test do
    on roles(:web) do
      puts "the task runs"
    end
  end
end
```

Or should I move that task into a `rake` task. And should I run that rake task within `whenever` and `capistrano`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jan, you may find documentation very useful https://github.com/javan/whenever. The code example below - I just copied and edited it from the doc.

```
schedule.rb

# run this task only on servers with the :app role in Capistrano
# see Capistrano roles section below
every :day, at: '12:20am', roles: [:web] do
  rake "app_server:task"
end

lib/tasks/test_task.rb

namespace :my_app do
  desc 'test'
  task :test do
    puts "the task runs"
  end
end
```

I believe it's easier to create Rake task and run it via Whenever. You can choose the Role, so basically you don't need to use Capistrano task (I believe you want to use it just because of Role).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest your latter option, moving the logic to a rake task and executing it from both whenever and Capistrano. It'll be vastly easier and cleaner to do.